# How do I enable Flash 11.2 in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I'm trying to force Chrome to use Flash 11.2 rather than the packaged Pepper version because it doesn't support DRM and I want to be able to use Amazon Instant Video/HBO GO. I followed [Adobe's instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-google-chrome.html#main-pars_header_0) to a tee but when I restart Chrome and view the plugins, the Pepper flash version is still the only one available. I have expanded the details and am certain I have not just missed the other version. I checked the directories where the files were being copied to verify that it worked and it appears that they successfully copied without issue. Unfortunately, since I didn't run into any problems until finding that it just didn't work, I don't have many other details that might help shed some light on this. I'm crossing my fingers though and hoping that someone else might have had some experience with this. Thanks in advance.

**Version Info**

- Ubuntu - 14.04
- Chrome - 35.0.1916.114
- Flash I'm trying to install - 11.2.202.359
- Flash packaged with Chrome (Pepper) - 13.0.0.214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can no longer get stock Flash 11.2 on Chrome because Chrome use the PEPPER plugin system, and the stock Flash Plugin is a NPAPI plugin. Google ended NPAPI support in April due to security liability's. I recommend Opera as its based on Chrome and it supports NPAPI

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realize that. Adobe should update their support page *fist shake*. I was worried that this might be the case. I'm pretty reliant on Chrome because I've given into my Google overlords and accepted their whole ecosystem. It's prevented me from moving away from Chrome on multiple occasions. I also think they have the best profile system. It might be time to move on though. Any reason you prefer Opera over Firefox or Chromium?

Comment: @austen What is exactly wrong with the standard pepper version? IF its that bad try Opera, it's pretty good, based on chrome and is compatible with the old version of flash.

Comment: It doesn't support Adobe Access which is basically the DRM for flash. This prevents me from being able to watch video on sites like Amazon and HBO GO. I'll give Opera a shot. I've been wanting to try it for a while anyways so I guess now's as good a time as any.

Comment: @austen I know Pepper flash had issues with displaying asian text but I didn't know it lacked AA.

Comment: Linux version of Opera isn't based on Chromium, it still uses old Presto engine. I don't think that Opera for Linux is still developed, as the latest version has been released 10 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Firefox, because NPAPI support in new versions of Chrome (with Aura interface) has been dropped. More information [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation).